# How do I stop IntelliJ searching for Incoming SVN Changes?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDE (12.1.4) periodically searches for incoming changes in my connected SVN repositories. When I first installed IntelliJ these incoming changes weren't searched for automatically - if I remember correctly I had to click on the refresh button in the Incoming sub-tab within the Changes tab and set some options.

I can't seem to know switch this off. Collecting information on changes seems to cause performance issues for me - maybe due to the remote location of the repository. Can't see any options in the system preferences, and clicking refresh, refreshes!

In summary - does anyone know how to stop Intellij collecting information on SVN changes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, like this:

- Go to the same place as where you turned the automatic refresh feature on (the version control pane, marked by `9: Changes`, and then the `Repository` tab)
- Hit the red X to `Clear` the VCS history cache (note: this won't delete anything important!)
- Hit the first icon with 2 circular blue arrows to `Refresh` the history, and now untick `Refresh changes every` checkbox and hit `OK`

The VCS history cache will be now refreshed once, but not periodically - refresh manually as needed.

And you're done!

Comment: That's done it thanks! I thought it was the incoming tab where I turned it on, not the repository tab as you say.

Comment: The same can be configured in `Settings` | `Version Control` | `Background`.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I am out of company network now. Because of this, Intellij cannot refresh even 1 more time.