# How to control Intellij Idea 14 - Indexing and VCS Refresh behavior

Tags: intellij-idea

Windows 7 64 bit, intellij 14
16 GB RAM, 1 2GHZ CPU with 2 cores

I have a huge legacy project with maybe 60 modules that I open with intellij.
And I only use it to view stuff.  I dont need to change anything in it.

Everytime I open it, Intellij goes through Indexing and VCS refresh history Dance, which takes a while and slows down everything.

Since nothing's changing really, I dont want it do index and refresh history everytime I open it.

1. How do I disable this or control this behavior?
2. Is there a way to manually perform these tasks?

Comment: The only reason why indexing may happen on every project opening is because an exception happens. You can check the log file (Help | Show Log in Explorer) to see if there are any exceptions. If there are no exceptions, indexing does not happen on every startup.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same bug and that's the decision:

1. go to settings - version control - background
2. set changelists to cache initially to minimal value (10)
3. check setting refresh changes every
4. set huge value for minutes (240 for example)
5. save settings
6. reload Idea

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if incoming changes were set to be fetched automatically in that project, the UI for this feature is a bit lacking.

This post covers how to disable it: [How do I stop IntelliJ searching for Incoming SVN Changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958877/how-do-i-stop-intellij-searching-for-incoming-svn-changes)